# Where did RedBean 4.0 BeanCanResty Rest Server go?

Tags: php, redbean

RedBean has in its API's an Rest Server till version 3.5 
http://redbeanphp.com/manual3_0/rest_server

I was wondering where to find RedBean_Plugin_BeanCanResty for RedBean 4? Since it isn't listed in the API any more. Is it still available? or is it deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

It's been removed, but is still available as a plugin according to their [changelog](http://www.redbeanphp.com/changelog):

Why are the BeanCan Servers gone?

They blurred the distinction between plugin and core. Also, the RedBeanPHP Adaptive branch is going more in the direction of a framework which is a better place for BeanCan as well. RedBeanPHP 4 returns to the core of the library: on-the-fly ORM. Another reason is that it turns out it is pretty much impossible to prescribe the interface of a JSON or REST API.
This functionality is still available as a plugin